# Rendering Problems: The following classes could not be instantiated. Answers to other questions haven't helped.

Tags: android

I'm currently doing an Android Developer Tutorial using Android Studio 1.5.1 and when trying to view my code in `content_main.xml`

I encounter the following message:
[Rendering Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3EEB.png)

Here is my `build.gradle`: 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cashcow.sunshine.app"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

I've seen similar questions but I haven't found a clear answer that applies to the error I have encountered.

Comment: Its there in the logs. You need to user Theme.AppCompat, check your styles.XML and try changing it

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate it.